# Java equivalent of C#'s HttpContext.Current.Items.set/get

Tags: c#, java, httpcontext, scoping, flash-scope

I am attempting to translate the functionality of a C# API, and I have arrived at some code that I cannot find a confident solution for.

It concerns storing data in the correct web-contexted scope. For now I could have fixed the issue simply by making a HashMap, but as I do not know the extended need for the data stored at this point, I want to go the length in trying to do it right. In my attempt to find a java solution that does the same, I have come across a scope I didn't know about before, namely the Flash-scope. It seems like it is the same as HttpContext.Current.Items, but I would definitely appreciate a second opinion on this. The flashScope is something i have discovered in the [playframework](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/api/java/play/mvc/Http.Context.html).

Also, HttpContext.Current.Items seems to be accessed in a static way, while java usually makes object instances of a scope class, like HttpSession.

Can I store objects in scoped dictionaries staticly, like in the C#-code below?
Is the Flash scope equivalent to `HttpContext.Current.Items`?
Can I access the Flash Scope without the Play Framework?

As always, I also very much would appreciate to know if I have made any wrong assumptions, or other misunderstandings.

Thank you :)

C# method

```
    public void setItem(String itemName, Object item) {

        HttpContext.Current.Items.set(itemName, item);      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpServletRequest` has the `setattribute()` method.

Comment: And `HttpServletRequest` is the same as `HttpContext.Current`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I see this answer has two upvotes, but I am going to downvote it. It doesn't even remotely answer the question. Throwing out a single line that a class has a method, without any explanation whatsoever, is not even close to what the question asks for.

Comment: Hi Bro. I only try to help you. But please, the attitud makes the difference. You asked for the equivalent, not equal. Java and C# are differents languajes. 'HttpServletRequest' it's a very used with 'HttpServletResponse'. All Java servlets have this injected variables by the server. I am attentive if you have more doubts bro.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean for it to become personal. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

This page provides a lot of useful information on the subject:
http://odetocode.com/articles/111.aspx

Among the most important lines are:

> An HttpContext object will encapsulate specific details of a single
>   HTTP request. Properties of this class include the Request object, the
>   Response object, the Session object, and an AllErrors property which
>   keeps an array of Exception objects accrued during the current
>   request.
>
> ...
>
> Current is a static property which will return the HttpContext object
>   for the current HTTP request. You can use Current from any object in
>   the logical thread of execution for the request

The data in `Items`, though accessed in a static way, are scoped to a single request. In other words, it would be logical to assume that using javas HttpServletRequest, and its methods `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()`, is sufficient for however the translated framework is intended to be used in applications.